# Apache can't load module because of GLIBCXX_3.4.26

Tags: docker, apache, gcc

I am using a httpd:2.4.46 docker image in which I have put my own httpd.conf and some personal modules.

The problem is that when I start the container, it works but the error_log shows he didn't manage to load my module.

[Mon May 17 10:00:25.279259 2021] [notice] [pid 12:tid 139994847216768] [mod-1.0.016] Failed to load /usr/local/apache2/modules/../../../../home/latest/module_gcc10.so.2021.2.1.003 : /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/local/apache2/modules/../../../../home/latest/module_gcc10.so.2021.2.1.003).

I've tried this for the moment : [GLIBCXX_3.4.20 not found, how to fix this error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error), in vain.
I am pretty sure it has something to do with missing things about gcc or g++ but I don't really know what to do.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module is linked against `libstdc++.so.6` version 3.4.26 (or later).

You *must* supply that version (or newer) of the `libstdc++.so.6` at runtime, or your program will not run.

- Note: `libstdc++.so.6` is part of GCC, it has *nothing* to with GLIBC.
- Note: you don't need to install full GCC into the runtime image, you only need `libstdc++.so.6` (and possibly also `libgcc_s.so.1`.

Comment: I included the installation of libstdc++.so.6 in my Dockerfile by adding this line: RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libstdc++6. After rebuilding the image, it still doesn't work and I got the same errror message. I checked into /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and I can actually find libstdc++...

Comment: @Samikaze "I included ..."  -- you installed the _wrong version_ of `libstdc++.so.6` (not new enough). You can see which `GLIBCXX_...` labels your version defines with `readelf -V  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`.

Comment: Indeed, I was somehow copying the wrong libstdc++.so.6 in my Dockerfile. I noticed it was smaller than the one in an other Docker image (working httpd server but too big), so I just made sure to copy libstdc++ from /usr/local/lib64/.  Thanks !